# How to for loop a certain pattern?

Tags: java, for-loop

```
dataValues[0][0] = dataValues_all[2];
dataValues[0][1] = dataValues_all[6];
dataValues[0][2] = dataValues_all[10];
dataValues[0][3] = dataValues_all[14];
dataValues[0][4] = dataValues_all[18];
dataValues[0][5] = dataValues_all[22];
dataValues[0][6] = dataValues_all[26];
dataValues[0][7] = dataValues_all[30];
dataValues[0][8] = dataValues_all[34];
dataValues[0][9] = dataValues_all[38];

dataValues[1][0] = dataValues_all[42];
dataValues[1][1] = dataValues_all[46];
dataValues[1][2] = dataValues_all[50];
dataValues[1][3] = dataValues_all[54];
dataValues[1][4] = dataValues_all[58];
dataValues[1][5] = dataValues_all[62];
dataValues[1][6] = dataValues_all[66];
dataValues[1][7] = dataValues_all[70];
dataValues[1][8] = dataValues_all[74];
dataValues[1][9] = dataValues_all[78];

dataValues[2][0] = dataValues_all[82];
dataValues[2][1] = dataValues_all[86];
dataValues[2][2] = dataValues_all[90];
dataValues[2][3] = dataValues_all[94];
dataValues[2][4] = dataValues_all[98];
dataValues[2][5] = dataValues_all[102];
dataValues[2][6] = dataValues_all[106];
dataValues[2][7] = dataValues_all[110];
dataValues[2][8] = dataValues_all[114];
dataValues[2][9] = dataValues_all[118];
```

I tried this but it didnt work

```
/*for(int k=0; k<3; k++){

for(int u=0; u<10;u++){

for(int t=2; t<120; t=t+4){ 

dataValues[k][u] = dataValues_all[t]; }}}*/
```

Comment: It didn't work because you commented it all out?

Comment: What is the exact relationship between dataValues[i][j] and the index into dataValues_all that you want?  What happened when you ran the code?  Please prove more detail in your questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++) {
    for (int u = 0; u < 10; u++) {
        dataValues[k][u] = dataValues_all[2 + (k * 40) + (u * 4)];
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, there are three sets of ten statements; the first of each set is {2,42,82}. Each 40 apart from the next value. My solution is essentially the same as the one provided by Marc-François, except I dispense with the intermediate variable, and pre-multiply the increment of 4 with the maximum value of the inner-loop, 10.

Answer (score 2):

```
int t = 2;
for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++)
    for (int u = 0; u < 10; u++) {
        dataValues[k][u] = dataValues_all[t];
        t = t + 4;
    }
```

Does it solve your problem?

Answer (score 2):

One loop will also do:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) 
    dataValues[i / 10][i%10] = dataValues_all[i*4+2];
```

Little clarification:

> `i/3` is a integer division by 3, so it generates 0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,2,...
>
> `i%3` returns a rest resulting from division by 3, so it gives: 0,1,2,0,1,2,0,1,2

Comment: Funny; I was just reading a question + answers on programmers talking about premature optimization and the tradeoff with readable code (http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/33020/when-is-optimization-not-premature-and-therefore-not-evil). Yes, this is clever and concise, but not exactly easy to read.

Comment: Yeah, but I also believe that others are not very more readable.

Answer (score 1):

```
for(int k=0; k<3; k++)
  for(int u=0; u<10;u++)
    dataValues[k][u] = dataValues_all[k*40 + u*4 + 2];
```

Comment: Please, put spaces between the variables, the operators and the numbers. It's ugly like that.

Answer (score 1):

If a nested loop like this isn't working correctly the single best thing you can do when debugging is print out the values of your loop variables and see if they are what you expect. For example:

```
for(int k=0; k<3; k++) {
    for(int u=0; u<10;u++) {
        for(int t=2; t<120; t=t+4) {
            dataValues[k][u] = dataValues_all[t];
            System.out.println("k = " + k + ", u = " + u + ", t = " + t);
        }
    }
}
```

See what it does. This will almost certainly show you what the problem is.

Alternatively, use a debugger and step through the loop watching those variables.

EDIT: Other people have given you answers that look correct; my intention here is to describe how to debug similar situations in the future rather than just giving you a specific answer to the problem at hand. I hope you find it useful!

Answer (score 0):

In order for your solution to work, in a single loop two variables must be incremented (u and t). You are doing separate loops for each of these which causes your iterations to look something like this.

```
dataValues[0][0] = dataValues_all[2];
dataValues[0][0] = dataValues_all[6];
dataValues[0][0] = dataValues_all[10];
dataValues[0][0] = dataValues_all[14];
dataValues[0][0] = dataValues_all[18];
dataValues[0][0] = dataValues_all[22];
```

The code posted above (by Marc-Francois) looks like the correct solution to your problem.